# Using `if` statements and loops/iterative calculations in Google Sheets

Tags: loops, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am building a recipe calculator and attached is a sample. Further down, I'm going to include some screen captures from the actual workbook too. In the sample sheet, you're going to see a bunch of #REF because the VLOOKUP in ColJ refers to a named range from one of the other sheets.

There are a lot of formulas in this sheet. As I'm not an expert, I simply focused on each individual function and then add it in. I am not experienced enough to do database architecture and as such, I'm not totally shocked something has started to break. I'm open to any suggestions and love learning so would welcome alternative solutions.

Here's the work flow for the end user:

1. In B2:B5 - a person sets variables. Most of them are data-validated dropdown boxes (using values from other sheets so I've just written in some text for example). By Setting this information, the vlookup in J gets to work and populates J4:J14.
2. This information is used in conjunction with B2:B5 to populate the data in B7:B9. J3 uses B8 and B7 to calculate a number.
3. ColD/ColE is where i think the problems start.
4. In the conversions table, people have the options to choose ways to change what happens ColD/E.

- The first variable is Ounces - when you select that, it takes a number in B11 and converts it from G to Ounces. This in theory would then update B8.  In B8, there is also a custom error message - the idea is that B3 and B4 are used to do some vlookups. If the value return = 0 then it means the person has chosen a setup that's not possible. Rather than get complicated with dependent drop downs (for a lot of reasons) i just have an error notice that tells them it's a bad combo.
- The second option is Yeast. This one is a little tricky but the idea is that it relies on the data in L:M. It allows a person to change the type of yeast they want to use and then convert the original value to the appropriate quantity of the newly selected yeast.
- The Multi-Flour option just allows people to partition the value in J3 or G3 (and thus E3). It's pretty self contained and most certainly not an issue.

5. Now we get to the feature that has caused me problems. This is the last feature I've tried to introduce and this is when the sheet starts to collapse. Up until i started this feature, the data in ColF and ColG didn't exist.

- if someone wants to customize the recipe, they click B15. I'll use custom formatting to show G2:G11. The information populates with the values already used in J. However, a person can enter a new amount. In turn the values in E will update. A person can type over the information in G and the new values will take precedent over the values in J.

In the settings I have the sheet set to do up to 50 calculations. I don't think it needs to be that high but just playing safe. The symptoms are that when I click B12, the value in B11 updates but the value in B8 does not. Perhaps I can get rid of B11 altogether but I don't know how.

The other major problem is that when I navigate around the sheet - the values in ColE flicker (sometimes the show up - sometimes they will disappear - etc...etc.... Though because they are broken references in this version of the sheet - you'll only see E3 flicker. I have a named function that's pretty robust and used inside some other functions in E6 (amongst other places). Here is that formula:

```
=IFERROR( IFS( AND(ISBLANK($B13),ISERROR(MATCH($G6,$J6:$J8,0))=FALSE),CALCYEAST(), AND(ISBLANK($B13),ISERROR(MATCH($G6,$J6:$J8,0))),$E3*$G6, AND(ISBLANK($B13)=FALSE,ISERROR(MATCH($G6,$J6:$J8,0))=FALSE),CALCYEAST(),AND(ISBLANK($B13)=FALSE,ISERROR(MATCH($G6,$J6:$J8,0))), $E3*$G6), "")
```

Here is a screenshot of the fully functional sheet before I added in the custom amounts options:

Here is what the sheet looks like now. As it's not a gif you can't see it flipping numbers around but if you look at E5, you can see it's displaying 0 when it should be taking E3*G5.

Comment: Turn off iterative calculations in your settings. No need for that and it's not keeping you safe. YOu have circular references all over the place. Cells can't reference both each other. Example cell A1 can't be 2 more than cell B2 if B2 is half of A1.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't turn off iterative calculations as I have a formula in another sheet that requires it (so far as I've been told and tested - the formula from the other sheet is:

={"#";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C<>"",(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()&":A")))&"P",""))}

Comment: Regarding the circular references, I'm pretty sure the places where it's getting me in trouble are rows 3,4, & 7 in G,E,J as well as B8. Do you agree? Because of what i'm trying to accomplish i'm not sure how to build the logic more effectively. Happy to elaborate on the idea behind those things.

Comment: @pgS Can you please provide/ reshare a sample sheet as there are